# How do I set some steps to automatically add to any TFS build definition?

Tags: tfs, build, build-definition

Trying to get any TFS build definition to come pre-equipped with nuget restore so we can get the packages folder out of source control, but don't have a way to make sure these steps are at the beginning of every new build definition automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force it. You can encourage people to use templates (either the out-of-the-box templates or templates you create yourself), but you can't say "only allow users to create build definitions based on templates".